# Difficulties plotting two lines into one graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have faced a problem with matplotlib. I have four lists of data, some rates and their corresponding years, some values and their corresponding years. I'm trying to write two lines into one graph, so that left and right Y axes have different scales, but the both lines share a common X axis. The other list of years is also little shorter than the other.

So this is what I currently have

```
gdp_years, gdp_rates = get_ordered_values(gdp_url)
un_years, un_rates = get_ordered_values(un_url)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Year')
ax1.set_ylabel('GDP', color=color)
ax1.plot(gdp_rates, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('UN', color=color)
ax2.plot(un_rates, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is the graph I have now.

[image]

Those scales seem to be okay, but X axis is not correct. I'm trying to get those year labels from the list to represent X axis, but I can't figure it out. Years should be from 1960 til 2018, but now the X axis shows from 0 to 60. Because of this I believe also the blue line is wrongly placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to plot the x-values, i.e. respective years. You should do

```
ax1.plot(gdp_years, gdp_rates, color=color)

ax2.plot(un_years, un_rates, color=color)
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should take a little break.. :)